# Enabling aggregate and compress CSS files resuls in vanishing theme

Tags: performance, css-js-aggregation

I used [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) for more compression on css and js files but it does not work for me! so I disable and remove it entirely.
After that when I enable aggregation of css and js files, my site's theme will disappear! even my administration theme! what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:

1. Again place advagg module's folder in your module's directory. Usually (sites/all/modules)
2. Go to database and truncate all cache tables starting with "cache". Do with caution.
3. See if site works.
4. Otherwise if you are having drush installed, check command "drush status" if it works. And clear the cache throudh drush again by command "drush cc all".

Hope this will help you. If not reply in comment I'll assist you to make your site work again.

Comment: how to truncate all cache tables? I have optimize_db module. is it OK if I clear all cache table in this module?

Comment: That is only for cache_form I guesss, truncate in phpmyadmin instead.

Comment: what do you mean about "truncate"? do you mean clean all the rows of the table?

Comment: I clear cache_form table but nothing happend.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your homepage and one of your admin page ?

Comment: you need the page without theme?

Comment: If page is completely blank add this code in starting of index.php file : error_reporting(E_ALLL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

Comment: no! the page is not blank! it loads all the content but without any theme and js

Comment: Try "sudo chmod 777 -R sites/default/files"

Comment: you mean I must set the permission of this folder to 777?

Comment: Try with this if works

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: ok no probs, can you see any error on page admin/reports/status

Comment: there is some errors that say: "Adv CSS CDN - jquery update Duplicate Functionality: Use jquery update instead of the advagg_css_cdn sub module.‎ " and "Adv JS CDN - jquery update  Duplicate Functionality: Use jquery update instead of the advagg_js_cdn sub module.‎" and "Adv CSS/JS Agg - Core Variables  Cores CSS and/or JS aggregation is disabled.‎" and "CTools CSS Cache Unable to create" .so what shuld I do?

Comment: You must try disabling this module and installing jquery update module from http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update . And for ctools css cache : "sudo chmod 777 -R sites/default" on terminal, cross check permission for your files folder

Comment: I have jquery_update installed right now. then I change the permission of sites/default directory but nothing changed!

Comment: is advagg module disabled ?

Comment: No it is enable, but now I disable and uninstall Adv CSS CDN and  Adv JS CDN sub modules.